# Retrieve special type parameter of recursive variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

Is something like that possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, class ...Ts>
struct third_t {

    typedef typename third_t<T2,T3,T4,Ts...>::type type;
};

template<typename T1,typename T2, typename T3>
struct third_t<T1,T2,T3,void> {

    typedef T3 type;
};

int main() {

    third_t<int,int,std::string,unsigned>::type z = "test";

    std::cout<<"string type: "<<z<<std::endl;
}
```

If yes, why isn't the specialized case found? I.e. it isn't even considered in the resolution.

I get the error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct third_t<int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, unsigned int>':

main.cpp:18:46:   required from here

main.cpp:7:56: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be at least 4)

     typedef typename third_t<T2,T3,T4,Ts...>::type type;
```

**update:**

I realized that my initial false presumption led me to think that I could "overload" a class as well, which of course is nonsense. Whereas something like that can be done with function templates, that

```
template<typename T1,typename T2, typename T3>
struct third_t { ... };
```

cannot be done with class templates, if so it would have been possible to extract the third-**last** parameter out of the template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why isn't the specialized case found?

Because there isn't a `void` in the end of the type list of

```
third_t<int,int,std::string,unsigned>::type z = "test";
```

If you try with

```
third_t<int,unsigned,int,std::string,void>::type z = "test";
```

compile.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask to get the third type using a "recorsive construction".

So I suggest the costruction of a type traits that get the n-th-type (where `n` is a template parameter) of a list of types.

Something like

```
template <std::size_t N, typename, typename ... Ts>
struct nth_t
 { using type = typename nth_t<N-1U, Ts...>::type; };

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct nth_t<0U, T0, Ts...>
 { using type = T0; };
```

So the third parameter can be found using the index `2U` (as usual in C/C++, starting from `0U`) as follows

```
nth_t<2U, int, int, std::string, void>::type z = "test";
```

Comment: Thanks,  that was the solution.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'm thinking about a possibility how I can make this more generic, i.e. without the ugly fourth void parameter

Comment: @FloriHe - but, exactly... what do you want obtain?

Comment: @FloriHe - sorry: maybe I didn't understand: do you simply want the third type of a list?

Comment: Yep, done with this recursive template construction.

Comment: @FloriHe - but why with recursive construction; or do you want a generic struct for get the n-th type of a list (where 'n' is a parameter?)?

Comment: Out of curiosity.

Comment: @FloriHe - answer expanded; hope this helps